# Forward/tunnel/transfer SSH traffic from/to Hyper V Windows machine

Tags: ssl, openvpn

Can I connect to VPN by using OpenVPN on the HyperV machine and then use it as kind of provider for the host, so I'll be able to work on the host but still access all needed resources?

Comment: I dont get the point what is the question and what are the business related purposes?

Comment: I want run openvpn client on virtual machine and use that connection from host

Comment: Please update your question, I still believe you may want to use it, for private purposes and this is offtopc on serverfault. It would fit superuser.com in that case. And it is still unclear what you are wanted to tell with "getting unwanted software"

Comment: @djdomi thanks for pushing me :) I re-phrased the question and tried to be as much laconic as I could. I removed all the explanations why do I want to do so, just how I want to achieve that

Comment: it's still out of topic. but in fact, yes you can install an OpenVPN client on a VM, and in case of accessing the resources from there if you want to reach them outside this will be getting a bit tricky with NAT and routing